# Cannot change the order of labels when migrating from iPhone to the iPad Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, storyboard

I try to extend my App to the iPad. So, after creating iPad storyboard, I simply copy/paste scenes from old iPhone storyboard. Everything works just fine, but I cannot move labels and pics around new iPad scene. I made for example different order of labels etc, but when I run simulator it looks like the same on old iPhone storyboard

Sorry, cannot post a pics because of reputation (( Thanks for your help!

Comment: Images: This is how I changed positions: http://goo.gl/st5qwL And this is how it still looks: http://goo.gl/d1xglb I also cleared all constraints and made sure I've got Universal App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you:

Change the project settings to be a universal app?
Set the project's main interface for iPad to use your new storyboard?

If those two are done I would check to see if you have any constraints on your layout that may have been copy and pasted over along with anything else.

You can try posting example images on http://imgur.com/ and linking them here.